# Which process intercepts ALT-TAB in KDE?

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

I have experienced that KDE stops responding to ALT-TAB (and CTRL-F1/CTRL-F2) out of nowhere.

Which process do I have to restart to get it working again?

Can it be done without closing all windows?

I tried:

```
$ kquitapp5 plasm
"Application plasm could not be found using service org.kde.plasm and path /MainApplication."
$ kquitapp5 plasma-desktop
"Application plasma-desktop could not be found using service org.kde.plasma-desktop and path /MainApplication."
$ kquitapp5 plasmashell
"Application plasmashell could not be found using service org.kde.plasmashell and path /MainApplication."
$ plasmashell --replace &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kwin_x11 --replace &
```

Seems to work.